# How to set optimal and correct relationships between three collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, database

I have a problem with correct relationship setup.

I have three objects in my application:

```
projects
sectors
employees
```

And I need to design relations for it:

a) each sector has it's own employees

b) each sector could be responsible for any project

b) not every employee is responsible in every project, in which participate the employee's sector and there is requirement to filter employees "by project"

So at this moment i get something like this:

```
sector has field project (ref: project._id)
employee has field sector (ref: sector._id)
employee has field project (ref: project._id)
```

Is that approach correct?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct approach is:

- sector should have employee id and project id
- employee should have project id